# how to give commands to the running instance of maya with mayapy.exe?

Tags: python, maya

I want to create a simple python script which will directly transfer objects from blender to Maya. I created a python script which exports the object from blender to a temp folder. now I want to import that object into Maya without actually going to Maya>file>import. I searched for the solution for a while and found out that I can create a standalone instance of Maya with mayapy.exe and work in non-GUI instance of Maya. but what I want to do is import the object into an already running instance of Maya(GUI version) as soon as the exporting script is done running.

Comment: You can use the [commandPort](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/commandspython/commandPort.html)  command in maya .

Comment: @AndreaRastelli Thanx for the comment! I searched about maya commandPort and found the solution. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by Andrea, I opened the commandPort of maya and connected to it using socket in python script. now i can send commands to maya using that python script as long as the maya commandPort is open.